# Error while setting up new Uptime check in Stackdriver

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am looking to set up a new Uptime check in Stackdriver for a service running in a GCE instance. I am supplying hostname as Internal IP of the instance. 
I am getting an error "responded with **Skipping Unsafe Address**".
Is there a way I can resolve this error?

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rrSF.png)

Answer (score 2):

If the resource you are checking doesn't have an external IP address, uptime checks are unable to reach it.  [Doc here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/uptime-checks/)